# How to Remove Extra White Space inside Body at Bottom

Tags: html, css

I am making an Article Based Website But getting A White space at bottom of 
here is the Problem
[See At the bottom Footer lorem line.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAHEF.png)

Here is the code can anyone solve it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="scss.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="con1">

             <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AAcHTtexpBPyQQMZKXRYF3APKZhGsVounjRCydXqOYv-ij6fCVo=s96-c-rg-br100"
                alt="">
            <nav>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <a href="#">About</a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="con2">
            <div class="ham_burger">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
            </div> 

        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="maincontent">
        <div class="leftside">
            <h1>
                Hello,
            </h1>
            <h2>
                Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem voluptatibus ut tempora voluptates dolorem perspiciatis dolor eum excepturi porro, ullam, nesciunt veritatis tenetur, cupiditate quidem.
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="rightside">
            <img src="https://jamesclear.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/atomic-habits-full-dots.png" alt="">
            <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cumque numquam necessitatibus asperiores unde enim rerum, ipsam, voluptas quibusdam non vitae consectetur sequi molestiae!
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Maven+Pro:wght@400;500&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Maven+Pro:wght@400;500&family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap");
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: 91px;
}

a {
  font-size: medium;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Maven Pro", sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

.con1 {
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  background-color: white;
  height: inherit;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
  gap: 3vw;
  padding-left: 6vw;
}
.con1 img {
  height: 47px;
}

.con2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: white;
  padding-right: 6vw;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  gap: 3vw;
}

.maincontent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100%;
}

.leftside {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 6vw;
  padding-top: 8vh;
}

.rightside {
  padding-top: 8vh;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
  align-items: center;
}
.rightside img {
  width: 37vw;
  height: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .maincontent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .leftside {
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .rightside {
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 91 px;
    padding-top: 8vh;
    background-color: yellow;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

I have given css and html code. I have used Red border to check what is causing the problem and it seems the body is taking full length but the component left side and right side isn't. But Cant find the solution .

Comment: why you have given your `html` tag `width` and `height` of 100%?

Comment: that doesnot have any effect tried all sort of things. And if you ask why i was trying solution from web

Comment: I just tested your project on my pc, remove `width:100%` and `height:100%` from your `html` tag  and it will be ok, and it's bad practice to give html width and height of 100%

Comment: I didn't bro. i copied from where i was testing to fix the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your body isn't as high as you think there to begin with.

Remove width and height from `html`.
Make body have `min-height: 100vh`, and also make it a flex container.
Remove the height from `.maincontent`, and add `flex-grow: 1` instead to allow the element to grow to fill the remaining space.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Maven+Pro:wght@400;500&display=swap");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Maven+Pro:wght@400;500&family=Poppins:wght@300&display=swap");
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: 91px;
}

a {
  font-size: medium;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Maven Pro", sans-serif;
  color: black;
}

.con1 {
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  background-color: white;
  height: inherit;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
  gap: 3vw;
  padding-left: 6vw;
}
.con1 img {
  height: 47px;
}

.con2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  height: inherit;
  background-color: white;
  padding-right: 6vw;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  gap: 3vw;
}

.maincontent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.leftside {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 6vw;
  padding-top: 8vh;
}

.rightside {
  padding-top: 8vh;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
  align-items: center;
}
.rightside img {
  width: 37vw;
  height: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .maincontent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .leftside {
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .rightside {
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 91 px;
    padding-top: 8vh;
    background-color: yellow;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
    <header>
        <div class="con1">

             <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AAcHTtexpBPyQQMZKXRYF3APKZhGsVounjRCydXqOYv-ij6fCVo=s96-c-rg-br100"
                alt="">
            <nav>
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                <a href="#">About</a>
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="con2">
            <div class="ham_burger">
                <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
            </div> 

        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="maincontent">
        <div class="leftside">
            <h1>
                Hello,
            </h1>
            <h2>
                Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem voluptatibus ut tempora voluptates dolorem perspiciatis dolor eum excepturi porro, ullam, nesciunt veritatis tenetur, cupiditate quidem.
            </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="rightside">
            <img src="https://jamesclear.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/05/atomic-habits-full-dots.png" alt="">
            <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Cumque numquam necessitatibus asperiores unde enim rerum, ipsam, voluptas quibusdam non vitae consectetur sequi molestiae!
    </footer>
```

Comment: So This works but Two issues  1) After changing to @mediascreen the white space added between rightside and footer  2)This is more like forcefully adjusting body and making it grow

Comment: There is no space being _added_, there is simply space _left over_ ... You will need to do the same thing again with `.leftside` and / or `.rightside` - allow them to _grow_ beyond what their content requires.

Comment: Ok, So this was kind of forced But I haven't seen anyone to use flex-grow. Isn't there any normal way

Comment: For a layout that grows to the height of the browser window, when the content is actually shorter than that, this is pretty much the standard way to go about it these days.

Answer (score 0):

The extra white space at the bottom of your body tag is due to the flex-wrap: wrap; property in . maincontent class

And in the styling of body tag,set min-height: 100% which will tell the browser to make sure that body tag is 100% tall

Comment: Sorry, But flex-wrap works only on mediaqueries so it has no effect on pc version